# How can I pick the difference between a HTML page initial visit and being reloaded via the back-button?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

*Disclaimer: I'm not very good with JavaScript. :-)*

I have a number of dropdown elements in a HTML form (some of which are only created based on the result of an AJAX request to the server depending on other form elements).

In particular, the user gets to pick a **country**, and depending on the country, they also get to pick a **culture**.

When the user submits the form, then uses the back button to redisplay the form, I've got javascript in place to rerun the AJAX requests and rebuild the dependent **culture** selector. I'm also using `localStorage` to track what they had previously selected as the culture so I can reselect that value after I've rebuilt the selector. All good.

What I've found, however, is that if the user goes back to the site home page and then navigates back to the page in question then the `localStorage` values are still in place. If they come into the form afresh I'd like to purge the previously stored culture. I only want it to be used if the back button is used.

I hope I've explained that ok. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You may just have to purge the `LocalStorage` when they finish completing the forms; alternatively use `SessionStorage` as it's bound by sessions rather than permanently set, hope this helps a little

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue. Two things:

(1) As @Shane said, I should have been using `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`.

(2) I was using `.ajaxStop` on the page `load` event to determine when the culture selector was reloaded and I could replace the stored value. This was also firing when the `country` selector was changed, and this caused the previous culture to be replaced. I've fixed that, and it's now doing all that it should.